# iphone application size installed is bigger than intended

Tags: ios, iphone, filesize

I have an iPhone 7, running iOS 15.7.7.
I see than applications take a huge place.
Looking deeper, I see that many applications on the device have nearly double the size that they are supposed to be (not talking about their data) when looking at their ipa or the iTunes library.
I tried to uninstall one and reinstall one, with no effect.

**Risk app into iTunes 12.6.5.3 library**
[image]

**Risk app size into Windows 10**
[image]

**Risk app size onto the iPhone**
[image]

Is this normal ? If yes, why ? and If no, how to correct this ?

Comment: I guess app thinning is involved, and also encryption. See: https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-builds/view-builds-and-metadata . On iTunes, try to check the build details in the Activity tab.